# Manually (re-)create Active Directory schema objects msExchRecipientDisplayType and msExchRecipientTypeDetails from Exchange on Samba AD

Tags: active-directory, exchange, ldap, samba4, schema

Somehow, my Active Directory has "lost" (at least) 2 objects from the schema. [`msExchRecipientDisplayType`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dkegg/2014/05/09/msexchrecipienttypedetails/) and `msExchRecipientTypeDetails` are what I need to recreate.

I believe they were lost, because my existing useraccounts have those properties. But now, when creating new users, I get an error about the above 2 missing from my schema.

That particular directory has no previous backups yet (new installation), but i'd still rather avoid a reinstall.

Possible solutions I see now are:

- Find somebody to extract those values from their AD (they are not secret) and find out how to apply them back into my AD.
- (Re-)construct an `ldif` with data like from the above link, and manually apply them with `some_tool`.
- (Re-)Run part of an installation routine to re-apply the schema extensions for `Exchange`/`Openchange`.
- A different solution/suggestion/pointer from somebody here @Serverfault

The enviroment is a mixed-OS domain. To apply the fix, I have Windows Professional with RSAT and Powershell installed, and Debian Linux Jessie Machines with samba4.2 and associated tools. The Exchange schema extensions are needed by `SOGo/Openchange`, which is installed on one of the DCs.

I guess, above is the generic question "How do I apply any additional schema object given a definition (file)" or the specific question "How to I reapply the Exchange Schema Extension (parts), in the correct version for current Openchange".

Please comment, if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually done this. But there are no other answers yet, so...
According to classes/documentation, things are never really delted from the AD schema, they are only marked inactive.

I am unsure what affect this will have on user accounts that were created when the attributes in question were deleted (aka marked inactive). I kind of doubt the attributes just appear on them. You may need delete those accounts and re-create them. You do have a test domain to practice in, right?

- Login with an account that is a memebr of Schema Admins.
- Launch ADSIedit and connect to the schema partition.
- Show "optional" properties.
- Find your attribute and open it.
- Change the "isDefunct" and/or "isDeleted" properites from True back to False.

It's the reverse of what microsoft desribes here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961741.aspx

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for answering. I am pretty sure, the objects were not in the schema partition (anymore), so I could not just change the isDeleted property. I solved it in the meantime. I found the ldif used during provisioning of the Schema Extensions. I copied the 2 missing ones out, and added them with <code>lbdadd</code>. Then I updated the Mail-Recipient class with an ldif  containing 2 added "mayContains" for the above missing properties. So, my problem is (manually) solved, but I was waiting to see, if better solutions/suggestions surface. Upvoted yours.